# pandas resample starting before the dataset first entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, resampling

Dear experienced community,
I can't find an elegant solution to my problem.
I have a subsample of my dataset which I want to resample weekly, but starting some weeks before the first entry in my data frame (so a few weeks with 0 counts)

A sample of the data:

In:

```
print(df_pec.head())
```

Out:

```
    Count Image_Sequence_DateTime
18      1     2015-11-06 03:22:19
21      1     2015-11-11 01:48:51
22      1     2015-11-11 07:30:47
37      1     2015-11-25 09:42:23
48      1     2015-12-05 12:12:34
```

With the earliest image sequence at:

In:

```
df_pec.Image_Sequence_DateTime.min()
```

Out:

```
2015-09-30 15:16:38
```

I have another function that gives me the starting point of the first week and the last point of the last week ever measured in that experiment, which are:

In:

```
print(s_startend)
```

Out:

```
Start   2015-09-28
End     2017-12-25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

My problem is that I want to resample df_pec weekly, but starting on the very first second of the very first day of the very first week of the experimental deployment.(using s_startend as reference)

I try:

```
df_pec=df_pec.resample('1W', on='Image_Sequence_DateTime').sum() 
print(df_pec.head(),'\n',df_pec.tail())
```

Out:

```
                         Count
Image_Sequence_DateTime       
2015-10-04                26.0
2015-10-11                92.0
2015-10-18               204.0
2015-10-25               193.0
2015-11-01               187.0 
                          Count
Image_Sequence_DateTime       
2017-11-19                20.0
2017-11-26                34.0
2017-12-03                16.0
2017-12-10                11.0
2017-12-17                 3.0
```

This is pretty weird because it is even skipping the first days of data in df_pec.(starting 2015-09-30 15:16:38)

And even if it worked, I have no way of indicating the resampling to start and end in specified values (s_startend from my example), even if there are no records in the earliest and latest weeks in my subsample df_pec.

I thought about artificially adding two entries to df_pec with the real start and real end, but I think it is not so elegant and I don't want to be adding meaningless keys to my df.

Thank you very much for your wisdom!